# How to migrate from MVC to Blazor Server-side?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm in the process of migrating my app from MVC (not Razorpages) to Blazor. Migrating the markup and the model was pretty straightfoward.

However, how am I going to migrate the controller actions? For example, I have a controller with 2 actions:

```
[HttpGet]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IActionResult Register(string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model, string returnUrl = null)
{
    ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

How do the above actions get migrated to Blazor?

Comment: Blazor is not a successor to Razor Pages - it's a new category in its own right, so I don't think it's right to describe using it as an "upgrade".

Comment: @Dai Correct. I need a migration path for the above then.

Comment: When you create a new Blazor App with Authentication you will see that the Login and Register pages etc are Razor pages. So this might not be the best example.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I know. That's because the Identity pages have not yet been updated for Blazor by MS.

Comment: _“That's because the Identity pages have not yet been updated for Blazor by MS.”_ – That’s not a goal that makes sense to follow with. The sign-in with cookies cannot happen through Blazor so this won’t be updated and it doesn’t make sense to attempt to migrate this.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provide is used to register users, might be you could consider using [Scaffold Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity) pages (it will using razor pages, instead of Blazor Component) in the Blazor server side application. Then, use these pages to manage Users and Roles.

If you don't want to use scaffold identity pages, and want to create Blazor component by yourself, you could create a Register component, then, write the component logic and event handling in the `@code` block. Check the following articles:

[Create and use ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

[ASP.NET Core Blazor forms and validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

And if you want to navigate to another page after form validation, you could use the `NavigationManager.NavigateTo()` method to redirect to another page, code like this:

```
@page "/fetchdata"

@using BlazorApp3.Data
@inject WeatherForecastService ForecastService
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
<div>
      @*display records in the web page*@
</div>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="submit">
    Submit
</button>

@code {
    private WeatherForecast[] forecasts;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        forecasts = await ForecastService.GetForecastAsync(DateTime.Now);
    }
    private void submit(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/counter");
    }
}
```

Comment: So basically I need a component for every action I have in the controller.

Comment: Hi @Ivan-Mark Debono, It depends on whether the action result needs a view to display the content or not, if it required a view page, you have to create a component, else no need to add the component.

Comment: So in the example above, how to I create the 2 components for the actions? One is Get the other is Post.

Comment: In the above example, I think you could create one Register components, in the Register's OnInitializedAsync event or OnGetAsync event set the initial data (like the Get Action), then add a button click event to handle the submit action. You can refer [ASP.NET Core Blazor event handling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/event-handling?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: What about the Post? Does it need to stay in a controller?

Comment: For the Post, you can add a submit button click event, then in the event save data into database, after success, navigate to another page.